# java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to write APN settings

Tags: android

In my android application, i want to change the device APN with android code. but it gives the Security Exception. i did many searches on google but didn't get any answer. if anyone know about this security exception solution then help me.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS);
                addApn(intent,MainActivity.this);
                startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

i used this method to post static data on APN Settings.

```
 private void addApn(Intent intent, Context context) {
        final String apn = intent.getStringExtra("www.airtelgprs.com");
        final String name = intent.getStringExtra("airtel");
        final String type = intent.getStringExtra("ope");
        final String proxy = intent.getStringExtra("12.25.25");
        final int mnc = intent.getIntExtra("mnc", 6);
        final int mcc = intent.getIntExtra("mcc", 724);
        final String user = intent.getStringExtra("SAnjeev");
        final String password = intent.getStringExtra("123456789");
        final String server = intent.getStringExtra("mera server");

        final ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Telephony.Carriers.APN, apn);
        values.put(Telephony.Carriers.NAME, name);
        values.put(Telephony.Carriers.TYPE, type);
        values.put(Telephony.Carriers.PROXY, proxy);
        values.put(Telephony.Carriers.MNC, mnc);
        values.put(Telephony.Carriers.MCC, mcc);
        values.put(Telephony.Carriers.USER, user);
        values.put(Telephony.Carriers.PASSWORD, password);
        values.put(Telephony.Carriers.SERVER, server);
        cr.insert(Telephony.Carriers.CONTENT_URI, values);

    }



      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS"
            tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />


java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to write APN settings
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:493)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:435)
```

Comment: The Snippet feature is only for JavaScript, HTML, and CSS code. Please do not use it to share other code like Java or Android code.

Answer (score 2):

the APN write permission is granted to system app only. you are facing this error because of permissions.

Comment: oreo is not allowing the WRITE_APN_SETTINGS permission to non- system apps.

Comment: i tried this code with kitkat, lolipop and marshmallow but didn't work on any device. so how we can give permisions to  non-system apps

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, this permission is not granted to 3rd party apps.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#WRITE_APN_SETTINGS

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're not getting permission in runtime. Try with this:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        int storagePermissionGranted = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS);
        if (storagePermissionGranted == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Do logic
        } else {
            PermissionUtils.checkPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS, 1);
        }
    }
```

And don't forget add on **manifest** the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: i used both menifest permissions or runtime permissions. but didn't worked for me and the same error occur

Comment: Can you update the question with the important source code?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem and tested it on Android 7.1.1.
You must convert your program as a System App, so follow the below step:

```
1- Generate App.apk
2- run emulator as writable-system(emulator file exist in SDK_HOME/tools)
       .\emulator.exe -avd {EMULATOR NAME} -writable-system
3- to see list of emulator name run this command
     .\emulator.exe -list-avds
4- run adb shell as root
    adb root
    adb shell
5- run this command
    mount -o rw,remount /system
6- copy App.apk to /system/app and /system/priv-app
7- reboot emulator
```